# Peercoin proof-of-stake: When a person with large computing power and a person with a large stake both compete to generate a new block who wins?

Tags: proof-of-stake, peercoin

In other words, if one user is trying to find a block using staked coins and another using PoW, which one will find it and why? Will there be a fork in the blockchain in this scenario? If yes, then how does the network decide which chain to accept?

I have a fairly good understanding of proof-of-work, and am trying to understand proof-of-stake correctly as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of fork, according to [whitepaper](https://archive.org/stream/PPCoinPaper/ppcoin-paper_djvu.txt), the chain with highest consumed coin age wins:

> The protocol for determining which competing block chain wins as main
>   chain has been  switched over to use consumed coin age. Here every
>   transaction in a block contributes its consumed coin age to the score
>   of the block. The block chain with highest total consumed coin age is
>   chosen as main chain.

In actual implementation, sightly [more complicated algorithm](https://github.com/ppcoin/ppcoin/blob/5ace24f056a06e37352c0dd861be8ab195aceaf8/src/main.h#L1269) based on PoS difficulty is used:

```
PoS_block_trust = 2^256 / (target+1)
PoW_block_trust = 1
```

And the chain with highest total "trust" is preferred.

So, the answer to your question is: PoS block wins.

Comment: What is the maximum possible value of target? Could target ever equal 2^256, thereby pushing PoS_block_trust below 1?

Comment: Even if it can, `target=2^256` means any hash is acceptable, so the block will be mined almost instantly (both PoS and PoW), and the target will be readjusted *very* soon, so it's not of much concern anyway.